# Obj-C performSelector OnThread in pthread C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a question about c++ pthread.

If I have a Thread1 and Thread2.

Is there a way to execute a Thread2 method on Thread2 called from Thread1?

```
//code example

//we can suppose that Thread2 call has a method 

void myThread2Method();

//I would to call this method from Thread1 but your execution  must to run on Thread2..

thread1.myThread2Method()
```

I would to know if exist a way similar to performSelector OnThread present in Obj-c.

Comment: Is your goal to call a C++ method from Objective-C on a background thread ?

Comment: You could wrap the C++ method call into an Objective-C method called with *performSelector:onThread:* .

Comment: no, maybe ... not only was clear obj-c is not used. I only use C + + and I would like to have something like is used in obj-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no similar way of doing this with pure pthreads.  This (the objective-C function you're referring to) only works on threads that have a run-loop, so it is limited to objective-C.

There is no equivalent of a run-loop/message pump in pure-c, these depend on guis (e.g. iOS, etc.).

The only alternative would be to have your thread-2 check some kind of condition and if it is set, then execute a predefined task.  (This could maybe be a global function pointer, which thread-2 periodically checks and executes the function if the pointer is not null).

Here is a crude example showing the basics how this could work

```
void (*theTaskFunc)(void);  // global pointer to a function 

void pthread2()
{
    while (some condition) {
       // performs some work 

       // periodically checks if there is something to do
       if (theTaskFunc!=NULL) {
           theTaskFunc();      // call the function in the pointer
           theTaskFunc= NULL;  // reset the pointer until thread 1 sets it again 
       }
    }
    ...
}

void pthread1() 
{

      // at some point tell thread2 to exec the task.
      theTaskFunc= myThread2Method;  // assign function pointer
}
```

Comment: I think that this is the closest answer to my question 
though is not what I wanted to do